# Angular2 - return boolean with subscribe to canActivate

Tags: angular, subscribe

I am new in Angular, I need to implement a function that returns true/false, I going to use the return in canActivate guard, but this function consumes a api by http.get, so like the communication is asynchronous this function always return FALSE, because http.get yet is in process.

My class guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    let url: string = state.url;


    if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }

    this.loginService.redirectUrl = url;

    this.router.navigate(['login']);

    return false;
}
```

and function isLoggedIn()

```
isLoggedIn() {

    let logged: boolean = false;

    this.http.get('api/values', this.httpService.headers())
        .map((res: Response) => {
            logged = res.json();
        });

    return logged;

}
```

I read many questions, but I don't found the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

guard typings says it can return

```
Observable<boolean>, Promise<boolean> or boolean
```

so change isLoggedIn to:

```
isLoggedIn() {

  return this.http.get('api/values', this.httpService.headers())
    .take(1)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

**update**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.isLoggedIn().map(loggedIn => {
      if(!loggedIn) {
        this.loginService.redirectUrl = url;
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
      return loggedIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Kit, but this way not call my api. if I change to: return this.http.get('api/values', this.httpService.headers()).subscribe(res => res.json()) my api is call, however res.json() isn't returned as value of function, how to return the result of subscribe as value of function

Comment: I edited my answer. In map() I didn't return value. Now it should work. Do not call subscribe() as it returns Subscribtion not Observable.

Comment: AFAIK you still need to add `.first()` or `.take(1)` at the end so the observable closes after the first event. Otherwise the router waits forever.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I'm sorry, but this way don't work. looks that only .map doesn't run the api. If I to use this way, I have that to call isLoggerIn() with subscribe:  if (this.loginService.isLoggedIn().subscribe( .... )) { }. I didn't understand how to work .map, .subscribe .... Why  http.get need these?

Comment: Observables are lazy and don't do anything until `subsribe()` is called. When the observable is returned from `canActivate` the router calls `subsribe()`

Comment: Got it @GünterZöchbauer, it works if I change my canActivate to:     canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {


        return this.loginService.isLoggedIn();

    }

, however  I'm not redirected to LoginComponent, how could be implemented correctly the canActivate?