# return boolean instead of subscribe to canActivate

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-routing

I have a component protected with canActivate guard. The Authguard in the `checkLogin` function subscribes from an observable but I do not know how to return a boolean value from it to canActivate.

**guard.service.ts**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

    public checkService:boolean;
  checkLogin(url: string):boolean {

         return this.loadAppSettings().subscribe(res=>{
              console.log(this.checkservice);
              if (this.checkservice == true) 
              {
                   return true; 
            }
            else{
                this.router.navigate(['/error-user']);
                return false;
            }
            });
      }//checkLogin throws error as type subscription is not assignable to type boolean
```

So what I want is if the `this.checkService` is true it should just return true and the user should be able to land on the guarded route but if it is false he should be navigated to `error-user`.

[Angular2 - return boolean with subscribe to canActivate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772181/angular2-return-boolean-with-subscribe-to-canactivate) this question is similar to mine but couldn't resolve my issue with it.

Can somebody help here.

Comment: @Igor is the duplicate still relevant if the asynchronous call returns an observable instead of a promise?

Comment: @DavidL - I would think so. An observable is nothing more than a promise with more calls on it. Also observable can be converted to a promise by using `.toPromise()`. Also the OP has shown that they can subscribe  to the observable, now its just a matter of them understanding how to use the whole concept of a callback.

Comment: @Igor my point is that it may be related, but it isn't an exact duplicate.  There are subtleties that make it a poor duplicate choice.  The OP's linked question is actually a far better duplicate.

Comment: Yes @DavidL exactly and if marked duplicate it will be left answered.

Comment: @AakashThakur I'm not giving you a free hall pass either :).  You are responsible for doing your own research to understand how callbacks and asynchronous code and you've already linked an answer that essentially solves your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

canActivate can return an observable too, see the definition [CanActivate-interface](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanActivate-interface.html). Just change your return types accordingly.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
}

public checkService:boolean;
checkLogin(url: string):Observable<boolean> {
     return this.loadAppSettings().map(res=>{
          console.log(this.checkservice);
          if (this.checkservice == true) 
          {
               return true; 
        }
        else{
            this.router.navigate(['/error-user']);
            return false;
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It says `Type subscription is not assignable to type Observable<boolean>`

Comment: @AakashThakur - sorry, that should have been `map` not `subscribe`, updated code.

Comment: Thanks alot Igor.

Answer (score 1):

**We can return Promise too like...**

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
       this.service
       .function()
       .toPromise()
       .then((res) => {
         if(condition) {
            resolve(true);
         } else {
            this.router.navigate(["login"]);
            resolve(false); 
         } 
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.router.navigate(["login"]);
        resolve(false);
       });
    });
  }
```