# getting variable data outside subscribe method

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient, angular-guards

I am trying to implement canActivate for user routes, before that I want to check whether the access token is still valid or not. Therefore I implement something like this

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  data:Array<Object>;
  constructor(private base: BaseService){}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    var session: any = { token: localStorage.getItem('abc') };   

    this.base.valid(session).subscribe(result => {
      this.data=result;
      console.log(this.data); <-- first 
    });

    console.log(this.data); <-- second
    return true;
  }
}
```

here I can get the data variable inside the subscribe method when I console it but outside this method is give `undefined` value. How can I access it outside the method.

Comment: you are missing this keyword

Comment: Your subscription has not finished before you call `console.log(this.data);`. That is the reason you get it as `undefined`

Comment: sorry but are you talking about the first console or second console log.

Comment: Ashish, please check my answer. Can you help me understand your logic so that I can suggest you something else as per your requirement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That won't be possible. The reason being, you are trying to render a value whose value is continuously changed by Observable.

Now, when you are trying to read `outside` **console.log**, you get undefined as the value is yet to be set by Observable `streams`. when the value is changed (let's say after 1 sec ), the `outer` console.log has already been executed and so you won't see any changes of the `this.data`

For monitoring the change in its value, put the function call in the `subscribe` block itself.

#### Update 1

As per your comment, You [can refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505024/return-boolean-instead-of-subscribe-to-canactivate)

Comment: ok, but how can i get this value, I want to return boolean based upon the value.

Comment: basically I am calling api to check the access token is valid or not. server return the `state`, now based on this state i am trying to return boolean value in canActivate method. here I am calling base api and then in subscribe I am checking state so that I can return boolean based on state

Comment: @AshishJambhulkar: Rather than checking the state in `canActivate`, you can move that **validation** logic to `BaseService` , lets say: `validRouting()` . Now this `validRouting()` can be returned itself from `canActivate` service (since it can return Observable) which will be of type `observable`. I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

The `BaseService.valid` returns an Observable which emits after the `canActivate` method returns.

The `console.log` after the subscribe block executes first, when `this.data` is still undefined.

```
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
  // 1.
  var session: any = { token: localStorage.getItem('abc') };   

  this.base.valid(session).subscribe(result => {
    // 3.
    this.data=result;
    console.log(this.data); 
  });


  // 2.
  console.log(this.data); 
  return true;
}
```

Comment: sorry its typo mistake, I already addes `this` keyword but still no luck.

Comment: Ok got it but how can i get this value then.

Answer (score 0):

```
public new_data:any=[];
this.base.valid(session).subscribe(result => {
  this.data=result;
  for(let data of this.data) {
    this.new_data.push(id:data.id, name:data.name)
  }
    console.log(this.new_data); <-- first
});
 console.log(this.new_data); <-- Second
```

Comment: you have to store the subscriber result in the new array using for loop as above and you have to declare the new array as public as given in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Well to be able to push data to the array you have defined, first you have to initialize it as an empty array so:

Instead of :

```
data:Array<Object>
```

try this:

```
data: Array<any> = new Array<any>();
```

This is what i use, hope it helps.