# getting undefined from data coming from firestore in Angular TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the value of the eventID I have from my firestore collection called Events. I am able to fetch and show all my Events in my firestore collection in my app but I need this `eventID` to complete other functionalities.

I'm new to TS and Angular and can't understand why this is not working

When I log my `userid` variable inside the auth function it works fine and retrieves the value, but if I do so outside the function it gives undefined.

Also when I log the whole `eventList` variable that I created to store the info from firestore it logs all the information, but if I try to retrieve anything, for instance, `this.eventList.eventID` or `this.eventList.title` it logs undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { async } from '@firebase/util';

export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  public eventList;
  public userid;
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, public fAuth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(){

    this.fAuth.firebaseAuth.user.subscribe(res => {
      this.userid = res.uid; //current logged in user id

      //fetch only events logged in user created
      this.firestore.collection('Events',ref=>ref.where("eventCreator","==",this.userid)).valueChanges().subscribe(event => { 

        this.eventList = event

        console.log(this.eventList)//logs all the info from firestore
        console.log(this.eventList.eventID)//logs undefined
        console.log(this.userid)//logs the userid
      });
    });
    console.log(this.userid)//logs undefined
  }


}
```

Comment: The reason it’s undefined in your last console is because the code where you set it is async. Also - never nest subscribes - very bad practice. You might want to read up a bit on how observables / RxJs works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get around the `undefined` data response issues that occurs with nested subscribes, use an RxJS `switchMap()` operator to pass the result of the outer observable from the `fAuth.firebaseAuth.user` observable into the inner observable, which is the `this.firestore.collection..` observable, which from there you can assign the event list from the streamed response of the inner observable all within one subscription:

Like this (I am not sure about the structure of your event data - either it is an array or a class/interface that is a header containing an array so I have placed an `any` as the response type):

```
this.fAuth.firebaseAuth.user
.pipe(
    switchMap((res: any) => {
        this.userid = res.uid; //current logged in user id

        //fetch only events logged in user created
        const eventListObservable: Observable<any> =                 
            this.firestore.collection('Events',ref => 
                ref.where("eventCreator","==",res.uid))
                .valueChanges()
                .pipe(
                    map((event: any) =>
                    {             
                        this.eventList = event;
 
                        console.log(event); //logs all the info from firestore
                        console.log(event.eventid); //logs event id
                        console.log(user.id); //logs the userid

                        return event;
                    })             
                 );
        return eventListObservable;
    })
)
.subscribe();
```

As best practice, you can assign the above to a `subscription` and free it later in the `ngDestroy()` handler.

A common issue experienced is with being able to access variables outside of the `subscribe()` block and is raised in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750121/getting-variable-data-outside-subscribe-method). If you try to access the component's `event` variable outside (and after) the `subscribe()` block, the variable will be `undefined` when it is accessed because the execution of the asynchronous inner observable has not yet completed and the code within it's handler has not yet been executed to initialize the variable.

Workarounds to the problem of variable access outside of the subscribe block include using:

1. An `async pipe` within the component's HTML template. (Convert the
   variable to an Observable first).
2. Use another RxJS method such as `combinelatest()` to subscribe to
   observables concurrently and handle them when they all have results
   ready from their respective observables.
3. Access the variable in another event handler from the HTML template.

To experiment and test the above nested observables use simple mock services first then attach your observables to the live services.

I recommend a good reference site [here](https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview) (which I also use quite often) for additional understanding (and examples) and more about how to use RxJS in these situations and of course other posts in SO.

Comment: will i be able to use the variables outside of the .subscribe() function?

Comment: You can still use the variables outside of the subscribe(). I will extend my answer to clarify what is possible and what is not in relation to the variables.

Answer (score 0):

**As `console.log(this.userid) // logs undefined`**

As `@MikeOne` refers functions inside `subscribe` is asyncronous. These function will usually be executed later. So at the timing  `console.log(this.userid)//logs undefined` is executed, `this.userid = res.uid;` still not be executed.

**As `console.log(this.eventList.eventID) // logs undefined`**

I guess `this.eventList` is array. Try `this.eventList[0].eventID` and so on to access each element.

Comment: How can i get the userid and eventID to be defined outside the subscribe function then?