# Can't access api response outside of its method

Tags: angular

I'm trying to fetch a list of users from a backend API. It all works perfectly unless that once I log the `getAllUsers()` method in the `ngOnInit` I get the data, but when I log the variable containing the list of users I get undefined.

Here is my code:

```
users:User[];

  constructor(private userService:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getAllUsers(); 
   console.log(this.users); // ==> shows undefined
    
  }

  getAllUsers() {
    this.userService.getAll().subscribe({
      next:(data) => {
        console.log(data); // ==> shows the result
        this.users=data
      }
    })
  }
```

Can anyone explain the difference between them? And how can I access the response outside the subscribe method? I'm still new to angular though! thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting variable data outside subscribe method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750121/getting-variable-data-outside-subscribe-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fetch from backend api is an asynchronous call, which means iydk takes time to load. That's the reason why the console.log in ngOninit shows undefined and the function doesn't. I hope it answered your question

Comment: Yes, I got it, thank you for that! Trying to figure out how to log the response now!

Comment: @Kaisama-x001 If you are trying to do some logic after `this.users=data`, call a function after `this.users=data` to do the logic

Comment: well, this is practically the best option I guess! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Within `getAllUsers` you do an **asynchronous** request. `next` is executed once the request is done and yields the result. However within `ngOnInit` you do the console log directly after *starting* the call. At this point the request is not done yet and didn't assign the data yet.

Comment: I got it, thank you! still struggling to read the data outside of the subscribe method